# What's the reason an exactly matched default comparison operator function is deleted?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider this example

```cpp
struct C {
 bool operator<(const C&) const = default; // #1
};
int main(){
   C c1,c2;
  auto r =  c1 < c2;
}
```

GCC and Clang [report](https://godbolt.org/z/1Kbnj7zcx) that candidate `#1` is implicitly deleted.

GCC:

```
'bool C::operator<(const C&) const' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
```

Clang:

```
defaulted 'operator<' is implicitly deleted because there is no viable three-way comparison function for 'C'
```

I'm not sure what the concrete reason is here. Specifically, the reason may be laid in [class.compare.secondary]

> The operator function with parameters x and y is defined as deleted if
>
> > 1. overload resolution ([over.match]), as applied to x @ y, does not result in a usable candidate, or
> > 2. the candidate selected by overload resolution is not a rewritten candidate.
>
> Otherwise, the operator function yields x @ y. **The defaulted operator function is not considered as a candidate in the overload resolution for the @ operator**.

The confusion is which bullet determines that the default `operator <` is deleted. If we ignore the emphasized wording, I think the reason may be the second bullet, since `#1` is not a rewritten candidate for `x < y`. However, if we consider the emphasized wording, `#1` will not be a viable candidate since it is a **defaulted operator function**, thus overload resolution applied to `x @ y` does not result in a usable candidate.

So, which rule actually determines that candidate `#1` is implicitly deleted?

Comment: The defaulted `operator<` is not considered a candidate. The overload resolution also looks for a spaceship operator, but doesn't find any. Therefore, the overload resolution doesn't result in a usable candidate, and the defaulted declaration is therefore defined as deleted.

Comment: @lgorTandetnik According to [over.match.oper#3.4], `operator <=>` can be a candidate for `x<y`. Since we cannot find that for this purpose, the defaulted `operator <` is deleted?

Comment: It could be a candidate, were it declared. But it isn't declared, so it isn't found by overload resolution. I'm really not sure which part you find unclear.

Comment: @lgorTandetnik Consider the formal [example](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare.secondary#3), `struct HasNoLessThan { };

struct C {
  friend HasNoLessThan operator<=>(const C&, const C&);
  bool operator<(const C&) const = default;             // OK, function is deleted
};` we do declare the three-way comparison and it is a usable candidate, and it is a rewritten candidate. However, the comment says the defaulted function is deleted.

Comment: I suspect that, while `operator<=>` here is a candidate, it's not a *usable* candidate. The rewritten expression for `x < y` is `(x <=> y) < 0` (per [**\[over.match.oper\]/8**](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#8)), so there needs to be a second overload resolution to find a candidate for `<` in the rewritten expression, and that one doesn't find anything. I agree the standard doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It seems like you know enough so that you could write an answer to the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes. Therefore, this is CWG2546.